# C# event problems

Tags: c#, events

I have some problems with my application. Heres the thing I have web cam that feeds the pictures into function wich calculate if there were any movements and where. But the problem is (my opinion) that event trigered by the new frames from camera are so often that the code doesnt have time to finish. So where could i put some semaphores or something if this is my code: (i tried many things nothing succsessful) :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FinalVideoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(VideoCaptureDevices[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);

        FinalVideoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideoSource_NewFrame);

        FinalVideoSource.Start();

        ImageEfects.drawGrid(detectionImage, 40);
    }

    public void FinalVideoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
            image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            #region demoInit
            if (initalization)
            {
                image1 = image;
                initalization = false;
            }
            #endregion demoInit

            ImageProcessing.calculateDiferences(ref image, ref image1, ref detectionImage);

            screen1.Image = image;
            screen2.Image = detectionImage;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe rephrase the title? It's pretty generic.

Comment: What are the actual problems? Can you provide the code that raises the event? If not, do you know whether each event is raised from the same thread?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't compare each and every frame. I would store a frame, than wait (count) a specified number of frames and than compare the current frame and the stored frame (in a separate thread). And store the current frame for the next comparison.

The number of frames to wait is up to you, that depends on which time lap is acceptable for you to overlook a movement.

Comment: yes, but if there is event fired up on every new camera frame how could i prevent this from happening. thats my question, Cuz if event accour the current code will stop from executing and it will jump to event handler right?

Comment: The event is fired, but if you do nothing but incrementing a counter that's no big deal. What I was trying to say is: only execute your code every n-th time the event is fired. But you should do that in a separate thread otherwise you may still build up a queue of events.

Comment: Apart from that I wonder if conventional event handling is appropriate here. Maybe you should take a look at [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a flag set at the beginning of `FinalVideoSource_NewFrame` which if set will let the function return. Toggle this flag at the beginning and end of your `FinalVideoSource_NewFrame`. That way you will never incurr in a queue if ever a computation cycle takes longer.